# GKE ingress Https Redirect - FrontendConfig not recognized

Tags: https, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have an GKE ingress with both Http and Https. I want to redirect the traffic from port 80 to port 443.
I found this:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/1075
which let to this:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#https_redirect.

The proposed solution adds a FrontendConfig with a RedirectToHttps flag which uses some LoadBalancer functionality. Yet when I try to add the FrontendEndConfig, I get the following error:

```
error: unable to recognize "ssl.yaml": no matches for kind "FrontendConfig" in version "networking.gke.io/v1beta1"
```

I have also tried 'networking.gke.io/v1' and 'v1beta2'.
The latest GKE version available in my zone is 1.17.13-gke.2001. I have recently launched the cluster so although I don't know how to check the GKE version, I reckon it's running on the latest version.

Anyone has a clue why my kubectl doesn't recognize this kind?

---

Ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  annotations:
    FrontendConfig: my-frontend-config
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: 'web-static-ip'
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: mycertificate
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 80
```

Redirect yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-frontend-config
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: I've tested here in GKE 1.17.13-gke.2600 and it runs. Check your server version using `kubectl version` look for `Server version`. Also, what is the region you are using?

Comment: Thanks for validating. Turns out I'm indeed running on GKE 1.16.13-gke.401.

Comment: Update your cluster version do 1.17.13+ to use this custom CRD for backend and frontend config. Let me know if it worked for you after update.

Comment: Just updated the server and I could indeed create the frontend config.

Comment: The redirect does not seem to work however. I added the frontend config also to the ingress so that's not the issue. Any chance you know what is causing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

I had to upgrade the cluster as MrKoopaKiller indicated and also changed the annotation:

```
FrontendConfig: my-frontend-config
```

to:

```
networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "my-frontend-config"
```

and it worked!

also: make sure you have:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
```

Comment: my goodness, `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"`  thanks! I was trying to figure out why it wasn't working for me.