# Using FrontendConfig for HTTP to HTTPS redirect in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

My apologies for this as I'm new to Kubernetes, on the Google platform.

What is the correct way to use the ***FrontendConfig*** CRD in *GKE* to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS at the Ingress?

There is a similar question here: [stackoverflow thread on FrontendConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140652/gke-ingress-https-redirect-frontendconfig-not-recognized/67293664), but that doesn't indicate clear steps

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @jsy, 
FrontendConfig's are another type of Kubenetes resource specific to Google Cloud's managed K8s service. It is supported in any GKE cluster from `v1.18.10-gke.600` and above. You can create one just like how you create other resources using yaml files. You can have. a look at the `Service`, `Ingress` and `FrontendConfig` files [at this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bank-of-anthos/tree/master/extras/tls-ip-selfsigned) for an example. Note that this example uses TLS certs, you can comment/remove those if not needed.

Comment: thank you. i will take a look. from a cursory glance, it looks like kubectl apply -f <yaml file> will do the trick. once i have done that, is there a way i can see these CRDs from the web console? or are they only visible via CLI?

Comment: You can view them in Google Cloud Console. When on the GKE window go to the `Object Browser` tab. Under the `Object kind` tab select `FronendConfig`. https://justpaste.it/7xnxs